# Returning Multiple rows from wp_postmeta table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to retrieve all the records that have a 
    meta_key = 'veteran_state' 
where I pass in the state to return all the records of veterans from that state.

The wp_metapost has 3 meta_keys:

1. veteran_state
2. veteran_name
3. veteran_website

I have been working on the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'veterans' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'colorado' 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

However, it returns only the veteran_state value.

I would like to return all the values for that state and render them to the browser as:

```
Veteran                    Website
John Doe                   http://website.com
Mary Veteran               http://mywebsite.com
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: do the filtering on the individual table and then join the results.

```
SELECT A.* FROM
  (SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value='colorado') A LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='veterans' AND post_status='publish') B 
ON A.post_id=B.id;
```

Comment: It throws an error: 

     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value='colorado') A

Comment: Still getting an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value='colorado') A LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT *' at line 2

Comment: Ah, no `FROM` I just added it.

Comment: Still getting error: #1054 - Unknown column 'A.veteran_name' in 'field list'

Comment: That means `veteran_name` is not an attribute of `wp_postmeta`. I have use `SELECT A.*` in the place of `SELECT A.veteran_name, A.veteran_website`

Comment: I appreciate your helping me. I have a new error: #1054 - Unknown column 'B.post_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: We are getting there. It returns just the veteran_state, and not the veteran_name, nor veteran_website.

Comment: That means you did not provide the corrrect structure of your tables. Can you produce a copy of your database on (SQL Fiddle?)[sqlfiddle.com]

Comment: Here it is in part, since it was too big: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f37bd1

Comment: Please create and add some data for the `wp_posts` table.

Comment: I added another record to sqlfiddle. Thanks again